# Android, RadialGradient only for one shape

Tags: android, canvas, gradient

I'm trying to add a gradient only to Circle, but it gos out of circle. How  can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
circlePaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getHeight() / 5, 0xff000000,Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, circlePaint);
```

And by the way everything white behind layer with circle, insted of TRANSPARENT. Why it so?

Comment: So fix:
circlePaint was in use for all shapes on my canvas, that was the reason))